# Подвисает страница при выгрузке фото

Tags: веб-программирование, клиент-сервер

Очень странная проблема.
Выгружается на странице галерея фоток, некоторая часть на загружается, и страница зависает намертво.

Открываешь другую страницу того же сайта в другой вкладке, зависает со статусом ожидание свободного сокета.

Проблема, похоже, браузерная, так как в сафари на маке открывается все отлично, но хром и мозила висят.

Что я делаю не так? )) Я пробовал грузить галерею без плагинов, просто тэгами img - то же самое.

В галерее примерно 30 фоток по 200кб.

Comment: А хром и мозила тоже на маке?

Comment: Да, но не суть, на винде также все происходит

Comment: @antshater, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Может, 30 по 200 кб (6 мб) многовато? Я знаю случаи, когда моззила не рендерила целые части страницы, хотя html-код был полностью загружен. Попробуйте все-таки эксперементально уменьшить размер картинок суммарно не более 3 мб, а то и менее.